# How to convert UNIX timestamp into EST time in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, utc

How can I convert UNIX time stamp to system time and date? In my case EST time.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989119/utc-to-local-hour-in-matlab

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/05/54806.aspx?Redirected=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [datenum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) to convert almost any format time string into a serial date number, then use [datestr](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) or [datevec](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datevec.html) to convert to whatever format you need.

Comment: But doing so, you ignore the fact that UNIX timestamps are UTC based, while MATLAB's datenum has no notion about time zones and thus work in the local time "area".

Answer (score 2):

Unix timestamps are often in the form of millisecs since midnight 1/1/1970, but sometimes in the form of secs since the same moment. Converting them to a Matlab datenum can be done via `datenum([1970 1 1 0 0 timestamp/1000])` (see [related Mathworks tech-note](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-9B9H2S/)). In case the timestamp is not in millisecs but rather in secs, don't divide by 1000. Once you get the datenum, you can use the `datestr` function to convert into a string in any format you like.

Alternately, you can use Java's `java.util.Date(timestamp)` to convert the timestamp into a Java date object, then use the Date methods to convert into a Java string, and then use Matlab's `char` function to convert it into a Java string.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and helped myself with a function like

```
function dv=datevec_from_timestamp(ts)
% Converts a UNIX timestamp (UTC based) to a (local!) datevec which can
% then be used as usual with datestr, datenum etc.
cal=java.util.Calendar.getInstance;
cal.setTimeInMillis(ts * 1000)
dv = [cal.get(cal.YEAR) cal.get(cal.MONTH)+1 cal.get(cal.DAY_OF_MONTH) ...
    cal.get(cal.HOUR) cal.get(cal.MINUTE) cal.get(cal.SECOND)];
```

Comment: Handling of milliseconds and having a vector for `ts` is left to the reader as an exercise.